# Form bound to disconnected in-memory recordset does not refresh

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a continuous form and onOpen event I create dynamically an ADODB.Recordset.

I use this values for the following properties:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
...
With rs
    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
    .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .LockType = adLockPessimistic
    .Open
End With
Me.Recordset = rs
...
End Sub
```

Everything works fine the form opens and the recordset data are displayed correctly.

The problem arises when a press the Refresh All button on the ribbon. Then all the records of the recordset are removed and only one remains with the #Name? value on every bound control . It must have something to do with trying to requery and being unable to do so since it is an in-memory recordset but I can not find what exactly or how I can fix it. Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong and how can I fix it?

P.S. I use the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to the problem finally was to change the Form Property Popup to Yes and 
Use the KeyDown Event of the Form to intercept the F5 And Shift-F9 keystrokes (With the Key Preview property of the Form set to Yes).